# How do I remove "GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)" and change the format of date & time on google docs?

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I am bulk creating google documents from a google sheet. The date & time are being added onto the google document in a different format with "GMT" added, compared to the google sheets.
Google sheets: [Sat], February 4, 2023 at 8:34PM
Google document: Sat Feb 04 2023 20:34:37 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)

My desired outcome is for the exact format of the google sheets:" [Sat], February 4, 2023 at 8:34PM "
to be copied into the google documents as it bulk creates them. Please not that I do not want to post the current time, only the time that is mentioned in google sheet.

**The coding coding for the google sheet [for LOGEVENT.GS]:**

```js
function logEvent(action) {
  
  // get the user running the script
  var theUser = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  
  // get the relevant spreadsheet to output log details
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var logSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Log');
  
  // create and format a timestamp
  var dateTime = new Date();
  var timeZone = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  var niceDateTime = Utilities.formatDate(dateTime, timeZone, "dd/MM/yy @ HH:mm:ss");
  
  // create array of data for pasting into log sheet
  var logData = [niceDateTime, theUser, action];
  
  // append details into next row of log sheet
  logSheet.appendRow(logData);
  
}
```

I am new to google scripts, so I don't know exactly how to code this according to this sheet.
Thankyou!

Comment: [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)